# Filter a Map by key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a map:

```
for (let jobInArray of jobs) {

  // lets me get rid of time, outputs to YYYY-MM-dd
  let deliveryDateString: string = new Date(jobInArray.DeliveryDate).toLocaleDateString("en-us");

  if (dateJobsMap.has(deliveryDateString)) {
    let jobsForDate: IDeliveryJob[] = dateJobsMap.get(deliveryDateString);
    jobsForDate.push(jobInArray);
  }
  else {
    dateJobsMap.set(deliveryDateString, [jobInArray]);
  }
}
```

Gives me:

```
dateJobsSortedMap:  Map(12) {"8/23/2018" => Array(14), "8/22/2018" => Array(19),...
```

I want to remove any entry that is older then the current date.

I tried:

```
let foobar = [...dateJobsMap.keys()].filter((item: string) => {
  console.log("item: ", item);

  let temp = new Date(item);

  return temp >= new Date();
});
```

But that returns empty.  It should return today's items (8/23/2018).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a date from the `m/dd/yyyy` template, its hours, minutes and seconds will always be `00:00:00`, but when you create a date with an empty input parameter - there will always be a current hours, minutes and seconds. So you can do this:

```
let foobar = [...dateJobsMap.keys()].filter((item: string) => {
  console.log("item: ", item);

  let temp = new Date(item + " 23:59:59");

  return temp >= new Date();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or set the hours on the comparison date to 0

```
let data = [["8/23/2018", Array(14)],["8/22/2018", Array(14)],["8/21/2018", Array(14)]];

let map = new Map(data);


let foobar = [...map.keys()].filter(item => {
  let temp = new Date(item)
  return temp >= new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
});

console.log(foobar);
```